# What exactly does the {'page': 1} mean here? "BuildError: ('main.user_profile', {'page': 1}, None)"

Tags: python, flask, web-deployment, werkzeug

I'm trying to make a Pagination object for 1 user's posts.
Everything's OK when the user is current_user:

```
@auth.route('/auth/edit_profile', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_profile():
    ###
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    pagination = current_user.posts.order_by(Post.timestamp.desc()).paginate(
            page, per_page=15, error_out=False)
    posts = pagination.items
    return render_template('auth/edit_profile.html', form=form, 
            user=current_user, posts=posts, pagination=pagination)
```

However if it's queried within the method like this:

```
@main.route('/user/<username>')
def user_profile(username):
    target_user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    if not target_user:
        abort(404)
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    pagination = target_user.posts.order_by(Post.timestamp.desc()).paginate(
            page, per_page=15, error_out=False)
    posts = pagination.items
    return render_template('user_profile.html', user=target_user, posts=posts,
                           pagination=pagination, page=page)
```

here comes this issue when it's compiled.

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError
BuildError: ('main.user_profile', {'page': 1}, None)
```

I'm aware that this sort of error is related to a route without its specific view function. In this case, does it mean I didn't specify Page-1-content or what?

Please kindly help me.. I'm learning coding from scratch 0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zyber is correct, but here's some more information:

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError
BuildError: ('main.user_profile', {'page': 1}, None)
```

is saying that there's no route named `user_profile` that accepts a named parameter of `page`. You *do* have a route named `user_profile`, but it only accepts a `username` parameter, as defined in

```
@main.route('/user/<username>')
def user_profile(username):
```

I can see that you're looking for the `pages` GET variable in the request:

```
page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
```

Please note that you don't pass the GET parameters to `url_for` in the template, as that makes Flask render them to part of the URL routing instead of as GET parameters. You don't have a method named `user_profile` that takes a `page` variable in the routing.

Instead, try

```
{{ url_for('user_profile', username=[username]) }}?page=[page #]
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that it cannot find an function that's called user_profile(If you are using `url_for`) in your main blueprint, and this function should take a parameter called page. For example like this.

```
@WebApp.app.route('/errors_log/<int:page>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@flask_login.login_required
   def errors_log(page):
```